# Find smallest value connected with arrays in 2 tables SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have table A with columns id (integer), group (_int8 -> array) and table B with id (int), group (_int8 -> array) and price (money). I have to find the smallest amount of money for each value in array in table A. For example:

Table A :

```
id | group
---|-------
 0 | {3,4,5}
 1 | {3,6}
```

Table B :

```
id | group |price
---|-------|------
5| {1}|100
6| {3,4}| 200
7| {3,5}| 300
8| {4,6}| 100
```

So for first record (id 0) i check money with first value (3) in all records containing that value. So it's with id 6 and 7. Next I have to return smallest of them so it's 200 (6). Next i do the same for second value (4) and it's 100, next is 5 and money is 300.

Next another row (id 1) so for 3 it's 200 and for 6 it's 100.

Now i have to sum all of that -> 200 + 100 + 300 +200 + 100 = 900

How can i do it in postgres?

Comment: Min price for item 5 is 300, not 100 and so the sum is 900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. Plese note that table `a` is first normalized (or flattened) using a lateral join.

```sql
select sum(minprice) from
(
 select v,
   (select min(price) from b where v = any("group")) as minprice
 from a cross join lateral unnest("group") as af(v)
) as t;
```